# How do I write a function that takes an array of values and returns an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

in this format; sample input: ["book", 1, "table", 4] sample output: {    string: ["book", "table"],    number: [1,4] }

here is the code i have written but it's not giving me the output i want.

```
function listDic(arr) {
if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    let output = {};
    for (let i =0; i == arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'string') {
            var str = [];
            str.push(arr[i]);   
        }
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
            var num = [];
            num.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return {string: str, number: num}
}
return "Only arrays are allowed.";
}
```

please what exactly am i getting wrong?

Comment: `i == arr.length` should be `i < arr.length`

Comment: You never use `let output = {};`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the type directly as key for the object, while iterating the array.

If you have not an object with the key, generate a new one with an empty array for pushing the actual item.

```js
var array = ["book", 1, "table", 4],
    object = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    var type = typeof a;
    object[type] = object[type] || [];
    object[type].push(a);
});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Ninja mode ... I think this is a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `str` and `num` in the loop without ever keeping any other reference to the arrays. Put those arrays in the output object, and then push into those.

```js
var data = ["book", 1, "table", 4];

console.log(listDic(data));

function listDic(arr) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return "Only arrays are allowed.";
  }
  let output = {
    string: [],
    number: []
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    switch (typeof arr[i]) {
    case "string":
      output.string.push(arr[i]);
      break;
    case 'number':
      output.number.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just reduce the array into an object, and use the type of the values as keys

```js
var arr = ["book", 1, "table", 4];

function listDic(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    let t = typeof b; 
    a[t] ? a[t].push(b) : a[t] = [b]; 
    return a;
  }, {});
}

console.log(listDic(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks i got a better way to solve it myself

```
function listDic(arr) {
if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    let str = [];
    let num = [];
    for (let i =0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'string') {
            str.push(arr[i]);   
        }
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
            num.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return {string: str, number: num}
}
return "Only arrays are allowed.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you :

```
function listDic(arr) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
        let output = {};
        var str = [],
            num = []; //CORRECTED
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { //CORRECTED
            if (typeof arr[i] === 'string') {
                str.push(arr[i]);
            }
            if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
                num.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return { string: str, number: num }
    }
    return "Only arrays are allowed.";
}
console.log(listDic(["book", 1, "table", 4]));
```

**Explanation**

Basically, there were two issues:

- you were really not entering the loop with `== arr.length` on your for-loop's entry condition.
- you kept re-assigning the `str` and `num` arrays with a re-declaration `var str[i] = []` OR `var num[i] = []`.

Hope this helps.